# Installing mysql on centos (not able to perform secure installation)

Tags: mysql, linux

I have installed MySQL on centos but I'm not able to set a password and also not able to perform MySQL secure installation because it asks password for root which I don't know.

I also tried these commands,

```
> service mysqld stop
> mysqld_safe --skip-grant
> update user set authentication_string=password('1111') where user='root';
```

but after typing the last command it shows following error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

What should i do now?

Comment: run `sudo mysql_secure_installation` If they ask for root password, do not type anything just press enter. Then it will ask to change password press y

Comment: @user3441151
i did but it says :

Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: try `sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log` then you will get your temporary password.

Comment: now it shows :

Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: When you try `sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log` then it shows an error?

Comment: @user3441151 no no , then it shows :

2017-04-11T12:35:00.412566Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: 7>f>+a2rQ
2017-04-11T13:11:47.388269Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: nPpq5CJ7Z

Comment: So you tried by these two Password?

Comment: yes 
it shows an error 

Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: run `sudo systemctl start mysqld` then `sudo systemctl enable mysqld` after that run again `sudo mysql_secure_installation`

Comment: [root@erewe ~]# sudo systemctl start mysqld
sudo: systemctl: command not found

Comment: try `sudo service mysqld start` then try `sudo mysql_secure_installation`

Comment: see now im actually able to login in through mysql -uroot 




but when i do mysql_secure_installation it asks me for a new password , which i entered and then re-entered and after that it asks :




Do you wish to continue with the password provided?(Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No)



obv my answer is y.



but suddenly it says :







... Failed! Error: The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement..






do you have any idea what does that mean ??

Comment: oh oh !! its done 

thankyou @user3441151 :) :)